# How to remove black screen with cursor on starting Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display

I have Windows 7 computer And by mistake have killed all the processes in the task manager and now when I start my computer it shows only a black screen with cursor.Please help me.

Comment: If you use `Restart` instead of `Shut Down`, the system restarts from scratch, instead of hibernating, which restores the previous state with the missing programs.

Comment: How can they do that if Windows is not loading?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean with "now when I start my computer", that you pushed the power button before ?

Try to hold down the "CTRL", "ALT" and "DELETE" -key at the same time, after the screen changes, you might choose among different choices. E.g. choose start Taskmanager and start a process e.g. "dvm.exe", it will start the GUI. You might also choose to restart your System(reboot), from  the choices, which will restart all default processes. By getting out the battery(without power plug), you can also restart your System.